# could not find the package in abp?

Tags: abp

I am using abp framework but now I can not find the package.

```
Volo.Abp.LeptonTheme.Management.Web
```

I have set the `nuget.org` and `myget.org`

`BlazoriseMyge`t and `nuget.org` both can not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a **commercial package**, which is why it is not publicly available on nuget.org

You can check https://abp.io/Packages for more details.

If you are using a commercial template, you should have **Nuget.Config** file containing a valid ABP Commercial Nuget source information in your application. You can also get commercial support at https://support.abp.io .